# PowerCLI transfers a file but the copied file size is way too small. What is wrong?

Tags: windows, vmware-esxi, vmware-esx, powercli, powershell-v4.0

I am using PowerCLI version 6 on a Windows server with 20 GB of free space.  I am trying to use copy-datastoreitem with PowerCLI.  It seems to work to transfer a .vmdk file from an ESXi datastore to the Windows server that has PowerCLI.  There are no error messages, but there is one problem.  The .VMDK file takes up 5 GB of space in the datastore.  The vSphere GUI reflects this.  The copy file, on the Windows server after the PowerCLI command runs, is only 1 KB.  Clearly the copy did not work correctly.

Is there another command besides the copy-datastoreitem command that works more effectively?

What would cause the file sizes to be so different? Using other PowerCLI commands, I found the 5 GB file (the source file) has the capacity for 35 GB of storage space as a VM.  It is a working, non-corrupt file.  The copy is not.  But my PowerCLI commands have no errors.  There is evidence that they work except for a huge difference in the size of the copied file.  The problem is 100% reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The descriptor file defines how and where the data of the VMDK image is stored. The data is stored in extent data files.](http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/VMWare_Virtual_Disk_Format_(VMDK))

I think copy-datastoreitem only copies a *file*, that is in your case: You just copy / download the descriptor file which **is** pretty small.

I didn't find a PowerCLI command to download a VMDK but maybe [Export-VApp](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/index.jsp#com.vmware.powercli.cmdletref.doc/Export-VApp.html) can help you.

On [reddit someone said](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/sev8a/downloading_vmdk_file_from_vcenter_comes_back/) that "you need to download the flat.vmdk, not the .vmdk, which is just the disk descriptor".